# xmonad + urxvt issue: text disappears after resizing

Tags: xmonad, urxvt

I'm using Arch Linux + xmonad + urxvt bundle and trying to resolve the conflict between xmonad and urxvt. Better to explain with shots:
Firstly, open the terminal and get some full-length output.
[Secondly](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45184302/2012-06-28-150845_1366x768_scrot.png), create another window, which squeezes the first.
[And, finally](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45184302/2012-06-28-150832_1366x768_scrot.png), close it to find out that half of the output disappeared.

Sometimes it behaves correctly, sometimes not. Tried to find out why, but failed.
Many thx in advance!

Comment: The initial state with only one window (su filter didn't allow to post more than 2 links): https://dl.dropbox.com/u/45184302/2012-06-28-150851_1366x768_scrot.png

Comment: There's a bug report for this here (not upstream though): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rxvt-unicode/+bug/677425

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to run your commands within screen. Screen wraps lines while resizing, but in this case, running a shell inside a terminal multiplexer may seem a little unaesthetic.

The second solution is to use the following code in your .bashrc:

```
for (( i=1; i<=$LINES; i++ )); do echo; done; clear
```

If $LINES is undefined, then set `LINES=$(tput lines)`.